# How to make an entire partialview in angularjs as popup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a simple application which is completely built on angular js. In routing, on every request, I'm redirecting it to particular partial as shown below.

```
.state('updateorder', {
    url : '/updateorder',
    templateUrl : 'partialviews/updateorder.html',
    controller : 'Distributor3Controller'
})
```

From the above code snippet, as you can see when request comes for updateorder, it redirects to updateorder.html

So Here my problem is, In my requirement I've to display updateorder.html as popup. And still it should be related to angularJs. So I cannot use concept like window.open(...).

My Questions are:
1) Can we do this? if yes then how?
2) Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. Have you checked [Nested States](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) in ui-router. Suppose that you have a state 'orders' which lists all the orders and then there is a link to update each order, when the user click to update, the state orders goes to its child state order.update_order which shows the pop up.